# Excel - Reading data, and combining rhe matches in different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I have an excel with two sheets. The first one has all the matches i work with, and the second one has all the teams, that make the pairs. In the second sheet, i have for every team some cells, where they can choose, some generic info about the time of their game (Weekends, weekdays etc). I would like to read the data in the second sheet, and

1. If both teams have chosen Yes to a common choice (for example weekends), to have it also in the equivalent column in the first sheet.
2. If both teams have chosen No to a common choice (for example weekends), to have it also in the equivalent column in the first sheet.
3. Ideally if there is a match in weekday/weekend and time, in the last column to appear for example "Weekend before 21.00"

Any help appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$E,MATCH(D$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$1,0))="Y",VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet2!$A:$E,MATCH(D$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$1,0))="Y"),"Y","N")
```

For the extra formula, something like this might be of help:

```
=IF(D2="Y",D$1 & " ","")&IF(E2="Y",E$1 & " ","")&IF(F2="Y",F$1 & " ","")&IF(G2="Y",G$1 & " ","")
```

Then again, it's just a collage of filtered header. I don't know if you were looking for something more sophisticated/specific (which would be less flexible).

Comment: The sheets are in this format [sheet1](https://imgur.com/Afxz1rI) [sheet2](https://imgur.com/BNWMSv0)

Comment: I'd suggest to add those picture the the question itself. Anyway: formulas updated. Send feedbacks.

Comment: it gets me formula error

Comment: You have accepted the answer. Does is still return an error? If so, send more detailed feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this with your formula works

```
=CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;Ζευγάρια!A$2:L$200;2;FALSE);"-");(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;Ζευγάρια!A$2:L$200;2;FALSE);"-")))
```